# Gretest Common Divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if gcd(m,n) = gcd(m,k) = 1, then gcd(m,kn) = 1

My opinion..;

1= m.u+n.v= m.a+k.b for some integers u,v,a,b.

We want to show that m.x+kn.y=1 for some integer x,y.

Multiply by k the both sides of the equation 1=mu+nv, we obtain k=k.mu+k.nv, also
Multiply by n the both sides of the equation 1=ma+kb, we obtain n=n.ma+n.kb. That is,

k+n=m.(na+kb)+kn.(v+b). Let (na+kb) be x and let (v+b) be y. Therefore, we have

k+n=m.x+kn.y

However, it should have been 1=m.x+kn.y
How can we solve this? Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply $mu+nv=1$ and $ma+kb=1$ together, and we have:$$m[u(ma+kb)+nva]+knvb=1.$$Let $u(ma+kb)+nva=x$, and $vb=y$, and we obtain $mx+kny=1$, which completes the proof.

Comment: Ahh sure! Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $\gcd(m,kn) \ne 1$. You have that $\frac{m}{n}$ is a fraction of lowest terms, while $\frac{m}{kn}$ is not. Thus we may write $\frac{m}{kn} = \frac{m/a}{kn/a}$ for some integer $a \ne 1$. Multplying our latter equation by $k$, we obtain $\frac{m/a}{n/a}$, which contradicts our original assumption of $\gcd(m,n) = 1$.